# Get text from XPath Element using Selenium WebDriver with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to use Selenium to get text elements from websites using Node.

As an example, I am using the URL: https://www.ebuyer.com/874785-exdisplay-gigabyte-geforce-rtx-2080-ti-gaming-oc-11gb-graphics-card-ebr2-gv-n208tgaming-oc-11gc and the XPath `/html/body/section/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/div[3]/form/button`

I can see in an XPaath selector plugin that it results in "Add to Basket", however the below code logs a blank string.  Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

I've tried it with a different element on the page which works, so I'm assuming because its a button?

```
const selenium = require('selenium-webdriver');
const chrome = require('selenium-webdriver/chrome');
const chromedriver = require('chromedriver');

chrome.setDefaultService(new chrome.ServiceBuilder(chromedriver.path).build());
const driver = new selenium.Builder()
  .withCapabilities(selenium.Capabilities.chrome())
  .build();

await driver.get(url);
await delay(1000);
const value = await driver.findElement(web.By.xpath(xPath)).getText();
console.log(value)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following `xpath` to identify the button.

```
//div[@class='purchase-info']//input[@value='Add to Basket']
```

**Update:**

```
const value = await driver.findElement(web.By.xpath("//div[@class='purchase-info']//input[@value='Add to Basket']")).getAttribute("value");
console.log(value)
```

Comment: I still have the same issue.  It succeeds the query, but the value is empty

Comment: @K20GH: To get the value `getText()` won't work here you have to use  `getAttribute("value")`

Comment: @K20GH : Please check the updated answer and let me know the status?